# Return inside if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, return

```
   def hi (n):
    if n<=5:
        print("we are inside hi")
        n+=1
        return n

n=1
hi(n)
```

1) In the above code i have declared a function hi() which takes an input n

2)I want to iterate  inside the if condition until n is less than 5,totally execute the print statement 4 times

3)But it is not working after execution of one time inside the condition

4)I am thinking i have given return statement for **if**  condition but the function is totally being exit

5)(i am thinking i am returning the n value to the if condition and it checks the condition and it will iterate  ) if wrong correct me

Comment: if you want to iterate you should use a loop: `for` or `while`.

Comment: can i know can we use return inside if condition (i am thinking i am returning the n value to the if condition and it checks the condition and it will iterate  ) if wrong correct me

Comment: `def hi(n): for _ in range(n): print("inside hi")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want to achieve, but based on the info you have provided:

```
def hi (n):
    while (n < 5):
        print("we are inside hi")
        n -= 1
```

Briefly speaking, using `return` inside a function means to return the value that is followed or return `None` if there is no value. In addition, the execution of the function is terminated just after the return statement is executed.

You can use the `return` statement, but if you want to iterate it is not correct because your function will terminate its execution. Also remember that once you execute the iteration of the loop, there won't be more statements to execute inside your function which means an implicit `return` statement will be executed which returns `None`, and again function ends execution.

Comment: I want to know whether we can use return inside if

Comment: @mdvenkateshnuhk, I updated my answer. I don't have clear exactly what you want to achieve, so hopefully this clarifies your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop for this. Try this instead

```
  for _ in range(4):
       print("we are inside hi")
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you need a loop to make iteration. If you just want to print the statement 4 times, simply make a range of loop.

```
def hi ():
    for n in range(4):
        print(n+1," we are inside hi")

hi()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
def hi (n):
    while n <= 5:
        print("we are inside hi")
        n+=1
   return n

n=1
hi(n)
```

you need a loop to iterate and return statement will exit from the function call.

Comment: while n >= 5 will fail for n=1 itself but he wants to print 4 times right?